# How to get htaccess to deny acess to a single I.P. on openshift?

Tags: .htaccess, openshift

I want .htaccess to selectively ignore some I.P. addresses.
I'm pushing the .htaccess file to http://modeldoc-treaties.rhcloud.com/wiki/extensions/log/ip.txt

I know that the .htaccess is being read because when it includes

```
deny from all
```

then I get the message "Forbidden".

But when I change the .htaccess file to say

```
deny from <my current I.P from whatsmyip>
```

then I'm not denied access.

Edit:  after shooper's suggestion I tried (to allow just me)

```
Order Deny,Allow
deny from all
allow from <my.ip>
```

which blocks me, and also (to deny just me)

```
Order Allow,Deny
allow from all
deny fro <my.ip>
```

which allows me.  So I guess the problem is I don't know what my i.p. actually is once it gets forwarded on openshift.

Comment: No space after the comma in "Allow,Deny" or "Deny,Allow"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift has a reverse proxy in front of your application, so the ip that shows up to your .htaccess file is not the users real ip, it is stored in the x-forwarded-for header.

Comment: @corey112358 Broken link: Behind IT Helpdesk.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably need the "Order" directive as seen at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html.

```
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from <your current I.P. address>
   Allow from all
```